# How to get data from radio buttons in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few radio buttons in my form. When I check the radio buttons I try to log them in console but now I want to get the text of radio button and save it in a state variable but I am not able to store it in state variable. There are 4 options in question 1 of the form eg: >=25 yrs, 26-35yrs,etc I want to store these age in state variable.

contactform.js :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class ContactForm extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            age:'',
            gender:'',
            health:'',
            name:'',
            email:'',
            info:'',
            fitness:''
        };
      }

    setAge(checkedValue){
    console.log(checkedValue);
    if(checkedValue === '-1'){
    console.log(this.state.age)
    }
  }

    render() {

        return (
          <div>

            <div id="center">
              <form>

                  <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <h3>[Test]Contact us Survey Form</h3>  
                    </div>
                  </div>

                <div id="agegroup" >
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <h4>What is your age group?</h4>  
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div className="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="age" onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'>=25 yrs')}/> >=25 yrs</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div className="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="age"  onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'26-35 yrs')}/> 26-35 yrs</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div className="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="age" onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'36-50 yrs')}/> 36-50 yrs</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div className="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="age" onChange={this.setAge.bind(this,'>50 yrs')}/> >50 yrs</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
    </form>

     </div>

          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default ContactForm;
```

Screenshot of my form:

[image]

Comment: where is your `setAge` function defined??

Comment: @pritesh Check my question I have edited

Comment: What should be stored in the `age`.Like should it be `36-50 yrs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically state will not get updated, you have to use setState for that inside onChange method.

Like this:

```
setAge(checkedValue){
    console.log(checkedValue);
    this.setState({
        age: checkedValue
    }, () => {console.log('updated age = ', this.state.age)})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.setAge = this._setAge.bind(this);
}

_setAge(age) {
  return function(e) {
    this.setState({
      age,
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.age);
    });
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <input type="radio" onChange={this.setAge('36-50')} />
  )
}
```

Comment: It should be `this.setAge('36-50')` or `this._setAge('36-50')`

Comment: `this.setAge` as you can see I am binding the function only once in the constructor.